# Unable to do assertion after page load in cypress test script

Tags: cypress

I have `re-invite/invite` button in my application I would my cypress automation script to click on the button. After click the button text gets changed to `Processing` I would like to do an assertion to verify `Processing` is visible. But the assertion part I am unable to do and it always give me an error.

this is the html before click
[image]

This is the html after click
[image]

This is the cypress code I wrote

```
cy.findByRole('cell', { name: /rita basu/i })
  .parent('tr')
  .within(() => {
    cy.findByRole('link', { name: /re\-invite/i }).click()
  })
```

how I can do assertion to verify `Processing` should be visible

Comment: can you provide html of the resulting "Processing" link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add:

```js
cy.contains('Processing').should('be.visible')
```

And your code should look like:

```js
cy.findByRole('cell', {name: /rita basu/i})
  .parent('tr')
  .within(() => {
    cy.findByRole('link', {name: /re\-invite/i}).click()
    cy.contains('Processing').should('be.visible')
  })
```

Comment: I already tried it but it did not work

Comment: it gives me this error  https://view.focusvision.com/z8ukDAKN